# I changed the icons in my XF application. The info.plist ITunes artwork 1x and 2x. But the icons don't change when I deploy locally to the phone

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Am I missing making some change?  If not then how can I make it so the phone displays the new icons I have just uploaded.  Right now it still displays the old ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the official [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1686/_index.html):

> `iTunes Artwork` is being used for `App list in iTunes`.

If you want to change the icon that is being displayed when the application is being installed, then you must change the [App Icon](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/app-icon/).

You need to create an `AppIconSet`, which will hold all of your icons - incl. Spotlight, Settings, etc. You can read more from the official Microsoft documentation where everything is pretty good documented - [Application Icons in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/app-icons?tabs=windows).

There, you will also find more information about [iTunes artwork](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/app-icons?tabs=windows#itunes-artwork).

Comment: I'm using Mac OS for development and the info.plist looks very different from the one in the doc there.  I cannot see any button for asset catalog.

Comment: In the link that I've sent you, you can switch between VS for Windows & VS for mac. Here's the link for macOS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/app-icons?tabs=macos

Comment: I agree with @Alan2, my info.plist in VS for MAC looks different.  There is no graphical interface, but just a property list.

Comment: I had to click the Application tab in the lower-left corner!

Answer (score 0):

1. In solution explorer, under iOS project, double click on 'Assets.xcassets' and change the existing 'AppIcon' icons or Add a new Asset and attach the icons.
2. In solution explorer, under iOS project, double click on Info.plist. Go to 'Application' tab, and change the 'Source' of 'App Icons' to the asset that you just created.